# JQuery: how do I see which events are defined on an element?

Tags: events, jquery

I use

```
$(window).bind( ... )
```

to set up event handlers, but for some reason I keep losing event handlers (i think).
Is there any way when debugging (firebug) to see which custom events have been added to a given element?

Yours
Andreas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All events bound by jQuery (e.g not inline events) can be accessed through .data

```
var $el = $('#someId');
var allEvents =  $.data( $el , "events" );
```

or

```
$('#someId').data('events');
```

its very rare I bind events to the window object but the same notion should still apply so try `$(window).data('events')`

This does indeed work demo [here](http://pastebin.me/494a1a1181c23) (writes to console so use firefox + firebug)

Comment: just figured it out myself and was about to post an answer to my own Q. you were lightning quick!